# Is the WiX Driver Element deprecated?

Tags: windows, wix, driver

Since the [DIFx Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/difx-guidelines) state that: "*the Driver Install Frameworks (DIFx) tools were removed from the Windows 10 Version 1607 WDK*" and the [WiX Driver Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html) relies on the WixDifxAppExtension, is the use of the Driver Element still the way to go to install a driver? Or should I use the [SetupAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/setupapi) directly (e.g. [as a DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570751/DevMSI-An-Example-Cplusplus-MSI-Wix-Deferred-Custo) which is called in the MSI)?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I just wanted to state that the WixDifxAppExtension works fine in 2022 on Windows 10.